# No se despliegan los parámetros de la plantilla variádica

Tags: c++, template

Tengo unas funciones que me calculan el valor máximo de entre dos e infinito parámetros:

```
template <typename T, typename ... V>
constexpr T maxvalue(T A, T B, V ... v)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(v) == 0)
        return A > B ? A : B;
    else
        return maxvalue(A, maxvalue(B, v ...));
}

template <typename T, typename ... V>
constexpr T maxvalue(T A, T B, T C, V ... v)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(v) == 0)
        return maxvalue(A, maxvalue(B, C));
    else
        return maxvalue(A, maxvalue(B, maxvalue(C, v ...)));
}
```

Se puede usar así:

```
std::cout << maxvalue(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 42, 15, 9, 4); // Muestra 42
```

Quería usar la función `maxvalue` con una secuencia:

```
template <typename R, auto ... I>
R f(std::integer_sequence<R, I ...>)
{
    return maxvalue(I, ...);
}
```

Pero al probar el código produce error:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << f(std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 42, 15, 9, 4>{});
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> error: expected expression
> return maxvalue(I, ...);
>                    ^
> ```

¿No debería haberse desplegado la plantilla variádica de esta manera?:

```
return maxvalue(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 42, 15, 9, 4);
```

Comment: Creo que te falta la variable antes de `...` o bien quitar esa coma separadora.

Comment: Ni lo uno ni lo otro, `I` es un literal y `...` es la expansión de los parámetros, por ejemplo `return (I + ...);` resultaría en la suma de todos los valores [ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tiUFgQG6gy6Wt1tS).

Comment: Acabo de ver ese ejemplo, en ese caso la expresión es sumar cada uno de los elementos de `I`. Si quieres pasar los parámetros tal cual entonces basta con poner sólo `I ...` como en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la siguiente línea:

```
return maxvalue(I, ...);
```

No estás indicando qué quieres hacer con `...`, siempre debe ir precedido de un operador que se aplica a un identificador (que debería ser `I`), por lo que si sólo quieres pasar los mismos parámetros entonces basta con dejar un espacio en blanco entre `I` y `...` para que se expanda correctamente como en este ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename ... V>
constexpr T maxvalue(T A, T B, V ... v)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(v) == 0)
        return A > B ? A : B;
    else
        return maxvalue(A, maxvalue(B, v ...));
}

template <typename T, typename ... V>
constexpr T maxvalue(T A, T B, T C, V ... v)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(v) == 0)
        return maxvalue(A, maxvalue(B, C));
    else
        return maxvalue(A, maxvalue(B, maxvalue(C, v ...)));
}

template <typename R, auto ... I>
R f(std::integer_sequence<R, I ...>)
{
    return maxvalue(I ...);
}


int main() {
        std::cout << maxvalue(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 42, 15, 9, 4) << std::endl;
        std::cout << f(std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 42, 15, 9, 4>{}) << std::endl;
}
```

Lo compilo:

```
$ g++ -o poc -std=c++1z poc.cpp
```

Y cuando lo ejecuto:

```
$ ./poc 
42
42
```

Comment: Ya veo el error, `I ...` ya despliega la plantilla variádica, la coma sobraba :O

Comment: Claro, aunque la coma podría servir para "inyectar" un valor antes del resto, pero lo importante es que los `...` se aplican a un identificador, no pueden ir solos.

Comment: No, la coma no inyecta nada. Al añadir la coma indicas que esperas una expresión (de ahí el error `expected expression`), es decir: `f(I ...)` se despliega automáticamente en `f(a, b, c, etc)` mientras que para que `f(I, ...)` funcione debe ser una expresión, es decir: `f((I, ...))`.